# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':nghinv_react-native-vlc:generateDebugRFile'

Tags: react-native, maven, bintray

Suddenly. I got the following error message when I ran the project again, it was working fine before, Maybe Bintray has shut down forever. And please tell me how to fix it without removing the library **ngnv_react-native-vlc**

[image]

Thanks all !

Comment: Try to clean cache and run again-> npm start -- --reset-cache

Comment: Thanks @RakeshSaini, I solved it by changing react native version in its root folder in node_modules